# Report viewer doesn't work on my visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, reportviewer

[image: here's the error.]

im stuck because i have to use the report viewer tool for it but it doesn't work. i have tried all of the tutorials on youtube and some of the solutions in other forums but it still doesn't work. This error keeps on showing up and i can't understand it. i can't even copy the error and i have tried looking it up but no results.

Comment: Smells like a .NET Core stack trace.  Use the right project template, it must have ".NET Framework" in its name.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things can cause problems with the viewer because it does more complex things such as invoking various database drivers.  There's been some bugs introduced since they moved SSRS integration into an extension.

Installing the older versions of VS/BIDS/SSDT that matches what the report was last developed in usually solves the problem.  We usually have multiple versions installed side by side in order to avoid these issues with SSRS reports.

Alternatively, I just build and deploy the report to an actual SSRS instance to view/test it.

These are viable workarounds if you're truly desperate.

Also make sure your SSRS Project properties have the correct SQL Server version targeted, and you build in release and grab the resulting *.rdl from the release folder to deploy to SSRS.